# how to append title if table has child with a class of

Tags: jquery

I have this example HTML , and i want to search the body and locate any tables within it that contain a specific class in their tablerows , then append each tables title to a newly created table.

So if body table contains class b.warning , append that tables title to #NEW div

```
     <body>

     <table>
      <tr><td><title>This Title</title></td></tr>
      <tr><td><b class="warning">Append this tables title</b></tr>
     </table>

     <table>
      <tr><td><title>This Title</title></td></tr>
      <tr><td><b>Do Not append this tables title</b></tr>
     </table>

     <table>
      <tr><td><title>This Title</title></td></tr>
      <tr><td><b class="warning">Append this tables title</b></tr>
     </table>

     <table>
      <tr><td><title>This Title</title></td></tr>
      <tr><td><b>Do Not append this tables title</b></tr>
     </table>

    <table id="NEW">APPEND TITLES HERE</table>

    </body>
```

I am not versed in jQuery but tried this

```
$(document).ready(function () {    

         $(body).find('table').has('b.warning').each(function (index, element) {

              var target = $("#NEW");

                if $(this).find("title").each(function () {   

                 target.append("<tr'><td>" + $(this)[0].outerHTML + "</td></tr>");

          });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at here : http://jsfiddle.net/pa5aLhma/2/

Your table's HTML is not really clean, I mean you have some errors, and you should rethink your usage of the [title tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp).

According to what you gave us I've changed the table structure to

```
<table>
    <tr class="title">
        <td>
            This Title
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b class="warning">Append this tables title</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, if you use this structure, in jQuery you do

```
$('table .warning').each(function() {

    var table = $(this).parents('table').first();

    table.find('tr.title').clone().removeAttr('class').appendTo('#NEW');

});
```

It is obviously not the cleanest way, nor the most optimised way to do this, but it will work.